# Order By Warning SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to merge data from different tables. I keep track of the item Prices so I have more than one price entry for a specific item. If no entry is found in the Prices table that means that the item is free.
Using `Top 1` and `Order by Id Desc` to get the last entry thought it will work, but SQL is giving me a warning of using it.

```
SELECT
(SELECT   TOP (1) CASE WHEN Price IS NULL THEN 0.0
                       ELSE Price END
 FROM  dbo.Prices
 WHERE (Id = table1.Id) AND (TableName = 'mytable')
 ORDER BY Id DESC) AS Price,

 (SELECT   TOP (1) CASE WHEN Price IS NULL OR DiscountPrice IS NULL THEN 0.0 
                        ELSE DiscountPrice END
  FROM dbo.Prices
  WHERE (Id = table1.Id) AND (TableName = 'mytable')
  ORDER BY Id DESC) AS Discount FROM dbo.MainTable as table1
```

> 'Warning: The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the the TOP clause in the view definition. The ORDER BY  clause does not guarantee ordered results...'

The expected result is to retrieve the last Price and Discount number from the other table

Comment: Add the following details : Full query, error message, sample data and expected result

Comment: 'Warning: The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the the TOP clause in the view definition. The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results...' The expected result is to retrieve the last Price and Discount number from the other table

Comment: Post the full query!!

Comment: That's the full query which produces the warning.

Comment: Cm'on now you have added `FROM dbo.MainTable as table1`.. thats what I was asking for

Comment: Don't you have `Order by` at the end ?

Comment: No, I retrieved the query posted right from the View. If I hit save the warning shows up. Apparently does not like the order by when fetching the Price :(

Comment: @user0187409 It's just a warning message saying that you can't predict the order of the result, it will just help in fetching the top records.If you want a specific order, apply an order by in the query where you are using this view.

Answer (score 1):

Use an aggregate and subquery

Something like...

```
 Where Id = (select max(Id) from dbo.prices)
```